# Can anyone convert this linq code into a SQL query (because I don't understand what is it doing)?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

```
var don2 = db.Panels.Include(y => y.Invoice)
                    .Include(x => x.PanelTypeEntries
                                   .Select(a => a.SubItems))
                    .Where(v => v.Invoice_Id == Quotation_Id)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: I have formatted and indented. Do you know what any of the keywords mean? You can ignore `ToList()`. `Include` basically means join to that table. `Select` means include that column only. and `Where` is self explanatory. Are you familiar with the underlying tables?

Comment: thank you for your concern my friend,
yes i am familiar with query language but here keywords like include confuses me .
i am new to linq and cant find a proper source to learn it

Comment: If this is actually in some running code, you can use `Console.WriteLine(dbContext.GetCommand(yourQuery).CommandText);`.  Ibeleive you can also use LinqPad

Comment: It is not "self explanatory." Are `x`,`y`, and `z` table names? What about `Invoice`, `PanelTypeEntries`, `SubItems`, and `Invoice_Id`? Column names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what is doing this piece of LinQ :

The code is using the `Panels` Entity set of you dbContext, that's mean the Panels table in your database.

Then, you are including an `Invoice` Entity, because it is part of your Panels one. It is most likely another table with a relation with Panels.

You are also including what looks like a collection of `PanelTypeEntries` to your `Panels` Entity. You probably have a N-N relation between those tables in your database. While including `PanelTypeEntries`, you are just SELECTing its `SubItems` property. Probably because `Panels` does not contains a List of`PanelTypeEntries`, but a List of `SubItems`.

The `where()` clause is the same as in SQL.

Finaly, the `ToList()` ask to the provider to execute the request and to store it in a `List`. That's why `var don2`'s type is of List.